# Unable to send terminal commands using Ruby

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, watir

I need to know how to send terminal commands through Ruby to execute another application. I would like to call the SIKULI script at a certain point within my Watir script to handle some steps that Watir can't.

I am not sure how to do it. I read a few of the articles here at Stack Overflow, but can't get it to work.

These are the steps to execute it manually:

```
jfleck-mbp:~ joe.fleck$ SIKULI_HOME=/Applications/Sikuli-IDE.app/Contents/Resources/Java
jfleck-mbp:~ joe.fleck$ java -jar $SIKULI_HOME/sikuli-script.jar '/Users/joe.fleck/Desktop/Save_File_Button.sikuli'
```

These are in a Ruby file I am trying to execute:

```
require 'rubygems'
system('SIKULI_HOME=/Applications/Sikuli-IDE.app/Contents/Resources/Java')
system ("java -jar $SIKULI_HOME/sikuli-script.jar '/Users/joe.fleck/Desktop/Save_File_Button.sikuli'")
```

The output I get is:

```
Unable to access jarfile /sikuli-script.jar
```

which tells me the first line in my script did not execute which allows the access.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it like this:

```
ENV['SIKULI_HOME'] = '/Applications/Sikuli-IDE.app/Contents/Resources/Java'
system ("java -jar $SIKULI_HOME/sikuli-script.jar '/Users/joe.fleck/Desktop/Save_File_Button.sikuli'")
```

The issue is that when you call `system`, you are invoking a child process.  Child processes inherit the environment from the parent processes (in this case your Ruby script).  Using `system` to set an environment variable sets it for that child process only, the next call to system is a new child process with a fresh environment.

The solution shown above sets the environment variable in the parent process, thus it will be set for all child processes.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* you're getting a different shell with each `system()` command.

One easy way to verify, and a more maintainable  approach, IMHO, would be put all the commands in a single (bash/zsh/whatever) script and run *that* with `system()`.

Comment: thank you for the response.  I am pretty new to ruby so I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: It's not a Ruby issue at that point, it's learning how to put commands into a shell script and call it from Ruby. The latter is trivially easy: `\`ls -al\`` is an example. For more examples  use `ri` to get documentation for `Kernel#system`, `IO.popen`, `Open3.popen2` and `Open3.popen3`.